# Headings inside of RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, radiobuttonlist

I've noticed that there is no chance to have different headings inside between ListItems in a RadioButtonList. So I have to splitt upp to diffrent RadioButtonList to be able to have headings.

Is it possible to do that without reloading the page or have it inside an update panel?

```
Exampel:

**Heading 1**

x Option 1
x Option 2
x Option 3

**Heading 2**

x Option 4
x Option 5
x Option 6
```

I only want one of the 6 options to be able to be checked

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure and I cannot check it atm, but I guess you can set a group property in properties of the control. If so, set the same group for all those.
Edit: yup, there you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname.aspx

Comment: Works great! Thanks alot! Put it as an answear if u like to have it checked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mark it as solved (for others who are interested in the solution):

> You can do this by setting the RadioButton.GroupName property!
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname.aspx